# How do you draw text on a <canvas> tag in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, canvas

I've been experimenting with using the `<canvas>` tag for drawing simple diagrams and charts, and so far it's pretty easy to work with.  I have one issue thought.  I can't figure out how to draw text on a `<canvas>` in Safari.  In Firefox 3.0, I can do this:

```
Chart.prototype.drawTextCentered = function(context, text, x, y, font, color) {
  if (context.mozDrawText) {
    context.save();
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.mozTextStyle = font;
    x -= 0.5 * context.mozMeasureText(text);
    context.translate(x, y);
    context.mozDrawText(text);
    context.restore();
  }
}
```

I've seen reference to a `fillText()` method in Apple's Safari docs, but it doesn't appear to be supported in Safari 3.2.  Is this just something that's currently missing, or is it some well-kept secret?

Comment: FWIW, `mozDrawText` is deprecated in favor of `fillText`. See http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas#mozDrawText.28.29

Comment: Yeah, I saw that but it's not implemented in Firefox 3.0, only 3.1 which is still in beta.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't believe that Safari 3.2 supports rendering text in the canvas.

According to [this blog](http://bottledtext.blogspot.com/2009/03/firefox-31b2-safari-4-beta-and-html-5.html), Safari 4 beta supports rending text to the canvas, based on the [HTML 5 canvas text APIs](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#text).

**edit**: I have confirmed that the following snippet works in Safari 4 beta:

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script>
    var context = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    context.fillText("Hello, world!", 10, 10);
</script>
```

Comment: Cool, I can live without text 'till Safari 4 is released.

Comment: What about the iPhone as of 12/14/2009?  What does it support?

Comment: And what about iPad 3 with Safari 5.1? Does it support fillText method with maxWidth argument?

Comment: @Slenkra I have no idea; I would guess it does, but I don't have an iPad so I can't test it. Why don't you try it out? Or if not, I'd recommend asking a separate question, so people who might know the answer can answer you.

Comment: I tried it and don't work.And I would ask but it's not allowed me.

Comment: @Slenkra You have asked questions before; why isn't it allowed now? Commenting here won't help you, though, since I'm the only person who's likely to see the notification and I don't have any iOS devices nor am I interested in them. The above example is how you draw text on a canvas according to the HTML5 standard, so if it doesn't work on the iOS version of Safari, then there is a bug in the iOS version of Safari and you should take it up with Apple. If you ask a question with the exact example that you tried and what didn't work, people are much more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: @BrianCampbell If I hit the ask question button I got this message "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account." So sadly, I can't ask question.. : (

Comment: @Slenkra Ah, you had too many downvoted questions. I've voted up one of them that you had improved. Can you try asking again and see if you have permission to ask a question now? If not, try improving some of your other downvoted questions. For example, don't just say "I tried X but it doesn't work", instead say "I tried X, and it did Y, but I expected it to do Z" or something of the sort.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't ideal, and it looks like you are fine waiting, but for reference, there's a library called [strokeText](http://www.netzgesta.de/dev/text/) that does its own font  rendering. It works in Firefox 1.5+, Opera 9+, Safari (I don't know what versions) and IE6+ (using VML instead of canvas).

Comment: Cool, but I'm using `<canvas>` for purely internal stuff right now and we all have Firefox installed (and some are using Safari 4 beta).

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to use the HTML5 text methods, you should try this library :
http://code.google.com/p/canvas-text/

and the demos are here :
http://canvas-text.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/index.html

It is still in alpha stage, so any bug report and feedback are welcome !:)

Answer (score 0):

I am using `<canvas>` tag to draw the Facebook logo, but the image, the text is stretched.

```
<div class="content1">
   <canvas id = "e" class="myCanvas">
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById("e");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.fillStyle = "white";
        context.font = "normal 64px Facebook Letter Faces";
        context.fillText("facebook",10, 100);
    </script>
     FACEBOOK
     </canvas>
</div>
```

CSS file:

```
.content1
{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:180px;
    height:120px;
}

.myCanvas
{
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    width:170px;
    height:60px;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-top:70px;
    background-color:#044692;

}
```